# PHP Composer scripts don't fire

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to get post install and post update scripts working in a Composer package. Here's an excerpt from the `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},

"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "App\\Install\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "App\\Install\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "./test.sh"
    ]
}
```

And here is `ComposerScripts.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Install;

use Composer\Script\Event;

class ComposerScripts
{

    public static function postInstall(Event $event)
    {
        $io = $event->getIO();

        if ($io->askConfirmation('Install Mecab? ', false)) {
            return true;
        }

        exit;
    }

    public static function postUpdate(Event $event)
    {
        $event->getIO()->write("Working!");

        return true;
    }
}
```

And the file `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Working
```

The ComposerScripts methods work if I test them with `composer run-script` and the `test.sh` script works fine, but when I install or update the package, nothing happens at all. No output, no error, nothing. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Just as a sanity check, exactly what commands are you running to install or update the package?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},

"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "App\\Install\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "App\\Install\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "bash test.sh"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and still nothing. Even if I remove the test.sh script, nothing happens even though the two ComposerScript methods should fire.